# Spree find product without any taxons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, spree

How can I find all the products in spree which have no taxons added?

If I run `Spree::Product.first.taxons` I get `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` with an array of the taxons which the product has but how would I find all the products where this array is empty?

I attempted

```
Spree::Product.where(taxons: nil)
```

but this returned

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column spree_products.taxon_id does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spree::Product.left_outer_joins(:taxons).where('taxons.id IS NULL')`

Comment: This gives the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "taxons"`

Comment: Is there no table called taxons?

Comment: Found the issue, the table is "spree_taxons" so `'taxons.id IS NULL'` needs to be `'spree_taxons.id IS NULL'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Spree::Product.ids - Spree::Classification.pluck(:product_id)
```

returns a list of all the product ids without any taxon which works well enough.